# How to make moving ball inside a box responsive?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, pong

For a school project, I'm making a CSS Pong game using no Javascript (loosely adapted from: http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-pong-insane-things-to-do-with-css/). I'm trying to make the ball constraint to the inside of the court area, and have it responsive at the same time.

I'm using media queries and the meta tag, but the ball is constraint to a smaller box inside the court area when the browser is larger.

I took a screen recording of what it looks like:

https://youtu.be/vF9b-2pi2nE

How do I make it responsive inside the court area?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Pong (1972)</title>

<link href="styles/csspong.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--custom google fonts-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:500" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<h1>PONG GAME</h1>
<div id="court">
    <div id="horizontal">
    <span id="ball"></span>
            <span id="player1"></span>
            <span id="player2"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>Computer vs Computer</footer>
```

CSS:

```
/*********************
        MAIN
********************/

h1{
    color:#3f3;
    text-shadow:0 0 10px #33FF33;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-color:black;
}

footer{
    color:#3f3;
    text-shadow:0 0 10px #33FF33;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
}

body:before {
/* background lines effect */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 50%, rgba(0, 40, 40, 0.25) 50%);
  background-size: 100% 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; }

/*********************
      PLATFORM
********************/

#court{
/*game platform*/
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    border: 4px dotted #3f3;
}

#court:before{
/*middle dash separator of the platform*/
    left: 50%;
    content:'';
    width: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 4px dashed #3f3;
    }


/*********************
        BALL
********************/

#ball{
    top:142px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background :#3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(10px,0,0)
}

/*********************
     ANIMATIONS
********************/

@keyframes twitchy {

100% {
    transform: translate3d(0,0px,0);
}
20% {
    transform: translate3d(0,-45px,0);
}
44% {
    transform: translate3d(0,25px,0);
}
46% {
    transform: translate3d(0,-15px,0);
}
48% {
    transform: translate3d(0,15px,0);
}
50% {
    transform: translate3d(0px,50px,0);
}
70% {
    transform: translate3d(0,60px,0);
}
85% {
    transform: translate3d(0,-30px,0);
}
95% {
    transform: translate3d(0,30px,0);
}
}

@keyframes updown {
/*keyframes for the horizontal id*/

0%,50%,100% {
     transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
25% {
    transform: translate3d(0,118px,0);
}
75% {
    transform: translate3d(0,-108px,0);
}
}

#horizontal{
    animation: updown 2.3s infinite linear; 
    /*having the animation seconds set to 2.3 changes the timing cycle to a more disorganized (random-looking, though it will repeat eventually) look*/
 }

@keyframes leftright {
/*keyframes for the ball id*/

0%,100% {
    transform: translate3d(10px,0,0);
}
50% {
    transform: translate3d(570px,0,0);
}
}

 #ball{
 animation: leftright 2.9s infinite linear
 }

 @keyframes query {
 0%,100% {
    transform: translate3d(10px,0,0);
}
50% {
    transform: translate3d(350px,0,0);
}
 }

 /*********************
        PLAYERS
********************/

#player1{
    top:125px;
    background:#3f3;
    position:absolute;
    width:7px;
    height:44px;
    left:4px;
    margin-top:-12px;
    animation: twitchy 2.9s infinite linear; 
}

#player2{
    top:125px;
    background:#3f3;
    position:absolute;
    width:7px;
    height:44px;
    right:4px;
    margin-top:-12px;
    animation: twitchy 3.2s infinite linear; 
}


 /*********************
    MEDIA QUERIES
********************/

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #court {
    display:table-cell;
  }
  #ball{
      display:table-cell;
      center:550px;
      animation: leftright 2.9s infinite linear

  }
  footer{
      margin:30px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 100px) {
      #ball{
        display:table-cell;
        animation: query 4.2s infinite linear; 
      }
}
```